# Shoutem UI Hello World example not working

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I'm working on react-native. I recently came across Shoutem UI. 
I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction). However, I'm getting this error screen. What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you do `$ react-native init HelloWorld` to begin with? Also, did you run `$ npm start` in the `HelloWorld` directory before doing `$ react-native run-android`?

Also check the last line of `index.android.js` and make sure you used AppRegistry correctly.

Comment: @VladimirVdovic I ran `npm install` and now it it shows `undefined is not an object` error and then it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationExperimental` doesn't exist past React Native v0.43.4, so you probably have v0.44 or higher.

You'll have to edit your `package.json`'s `react-native` dependency:

`"react-native": "^0.43.0"`

Afterwards:

```
$ cd ProjectName
$ rm -rf node_modules     //get rid of previous dependencies
$ npm install             //install dependencies from package.json
$ react-native link
$ react-native run-android
```

This solution is from a [github issue](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/241#issuecomment-298602614), from the user dobrienlzd.